# c++ Simple code with classes

Tags: c++, class

I'm writing a cpp program and i ran into a problem. It looks "easy" but still cant find out how to get rid of it.

Here's a simplified version of the problem:

```
class a
{
public:
    int number;
    a();
    a(int x);
    void set_num(int n);
};
a::a()
{

}

a::a(int x)
{
    number = x;
}
void a::set_num(int n)
{
    number = n;
}

class b
{
public:
    a abcdef();

    b();
    b(int x);
};

b::b(int x)
{
    abcdef.set_num(x);
}
```

I want to use "class a"-s copy in "class b" and i want to give it a value with the "set_num" function in "b"-s constructor after i created it with its default constructor ("a abcdef();")

But when i run the code it says:

error: '((b*)this)->b::abcdef' does not have class type.

Any idea, how to solve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `abcdef` is declared as a function that returns an `a`. Change that line to `a abcdef;` (without the `()`) to declare a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write:

```
    a abcdef();  // oops, do you really want this ?
```

it means that you have a member function in you `b` class, that takes no argument and return an a.

From your explanation I understand that you certainly wanted an `a` object as member:

```
    a abcdef;  // this is a member variable that you can set with setnum.
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not defining a member of type `a` but a function that takes no parameters and returns an `a`.

Instead write:

```
a abcdef;
```